# page view counter, code is provided, is it the best way?

Tags: php, mysql, counter

lets assume we have this table called `visits` and it has two fields `id` for the page id and `ip` for the user's ip address.

I have written this code and I'm wondering if it's the best way?

```
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $query = "SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(ip) FROM visits WHERE id = '{$id}' AND WHERE ip ='{$ip}') as visited,
    (SELECT COUNT(ip) FROM visits WHERE id = '{$id}') as pageHits";

    $result=mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $pageHits=$row['pageHits'];
    $visited=$row['visited']; //it's either 0 or 1;

    if($visited==0){
        $query ="INSERT INTO visits (ip , id) VALUES ('{$ip}', {$id})"
        $result=mysql_query($query, $connection);
        $pageHits++;
    }

    echo $pageHits;
```

Comment: Once the user visited any of the page ,it sets the visited flag to 1 , so hit counter will not track any of the other pages in future. Because ip address will same for all pages

Comment: You'd probably be better of just adding a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(ip, id)` - otherwise you wind up with a race condition.

Comment: Make sure you sanitize the GET parameter. Its an open vulnerability in your code as it currently stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not even check for an existing entry in the database.

Add a `UNIQUE` Key on `ip` and `id` (combined) and just run an `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO visits (ip, id) VALUES ('.$ip.', '.intval($id).')';
mysql_query($query, $connection);

// and now select the visits:
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(ip) as pageHits FROM visits WHERE id = '.intval($id);
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
list($pageHits) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $pageHits;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much depends on the use case you have. For a trivial counter in an internal network this may be sufficient.

Though I'm not quite clear what "pageHits" actually counts. Seems to be the number of unique visitors which I wouldn't call "pageHits".

For a website visible by everyone the approach is problematic. One obvious issue is the vulnerability to an SQL injection via the "id" parameter.

There are of course plenty of libraries available that do such a counting with various degrees of complexity. Without further details and the actual use case you have it is hard to tell if you need to code something more complex or not.